# Is the permission parameter case-sensitive when using with hasPermission in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, permissions

Do the below two lines behave the same way?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#task, 'MANAGER')

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#task, 'manager')
```

Also, the permission constant is defined as below in the CustomPermission.java

```
 public static final Permission MANAGER    = new CustomPermission(1<<7,'M');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the permission parameter case-sensitive? Well, yes and no. If the permission is an uppercase `String` and you input a lowercase permission, it will work. The opposite won't, though.

I checked Spring's source code. `AclPermissionEvaluator` is the default implementation of `PermissionEvaluator`, which is the interface that handles the `hasPermission()` routine. It tries to find the permission from the original given `String` first. If it doesn't find it, it tries again calling `toUpperCase()`.

See it for yourself:

```
if (permission instanceof String) {
    String permString = (String) permission;
    Permission p;

    try {
        p = permissionFactory.buildFromName(permString);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException notfound) {
        p = permissionFactory.buildFromName(permString.toUpperCase());
    }

    if (p != null) {
        return Arrays.asList(p);
    }

}
```

---

Reference:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7b4a37f27e4ba7045bd63656e49ee0d5ee381ce5/acl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.java